# increase Max file size limit that can be uploaded in VSTS testcase results attachment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

Need steps to increase file size limit from the standard 100 mb to say 300mb. what are the configurations that are required for this?

Thanks

[image: sample test run]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> increase Max file size limit that can be uploaded in VSTS testcase results attachment

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid there is no such operations are supported for test run attachment at this moment.

There is no such configuration in TFS related to 100M limitation. this should related to the REST API limitation. But there is no such configuration settings web service for test run attachment, like [Changing the maximum attachment size for work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/change-maximum-attachment-size-work-items?view=azure-devops#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20Azure%20DevOps%20and,group%2C%20get%20added%20as%20one.):

[image]

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps Server.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer to this Leo.